# Models in a Wicket FormComponentPanel

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, wicket

I've created a FormComponentPanel to represent the current time which consists of 3 drop downs for hour and minute and meridiem.
The model object of the FormComponentPanel is a Date object and the model of each drop down represents the selected option, but I need to change the model object in my component according to the options chosen from the drop downs. How can I do that?

Note: I cannot use any other component at this point of the development... I just need to able to get accurate data from the model object.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use java.util.Calendar instead or even better: [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I think java.util.Date can be used via 2 ComponentPropertyModel objects, accessing getters/setters as properties "hours", "minutes".
I have no simple idea for "meridiem" property, this need to be coded. 
Or use 24h.